# Can LMDB be made concurrent for writes as well under specific circumstances?

Tags: lmdb

MDB_NOLOCK as described at [mdb_env_open()](http://www.lmdb.tech/doc/group__mdb.html#ga32a193c6bf4d7d5c5d579e71f22e9340) apidoc:

> MDB_NOLOCK Don't do any locking. If concurrent access is anticipated, the caller must manage all concurrency itself. For proper operation the caller must enforce single-writer semantics, and must ensure that no readers are using old transactions while a writer is active. The simplest approach is to use an exclusive lock so that no readers may be active at all when a writer begins.

1. What if an RW txnA intends to modify a set of keys which has no key in common with another set of keys which another RW txnB intends to modify? Couldn't they be sent concurrently?
2. Isn't the single-writer semantic wasteful for such situations? As one txn is waiting for the previous one to finish, even though they intend to operate in entirely separate regions in an lmdb env.
3. In an environment opened with `MDB_NOLOCK`, what if the client app calculates in the domainland, that two write transactions are intending to RW to mutually exclusive set of keys anywhere in an lmdb environment, and sends only such transactions concurrently anyway? What could go wrong?
4. Could such concurrent writes scale linearly with cores? Like RO txns do? Given the app is able to manage these concurrent writes, in the manner described in 3.

Answer (score 2):

1. No, since modifying key/value pairs requires also modifying the b-tree structure, and the two transactions would conflict with each other.
2. You should avoid doing long-running computations in the middle of a write transaction. Try to do as much as possible beforehand. If you can't do this, then LMDB might not be a great fit for you application. Usually you can though.
3. Very bad stuff. Application crashes and DB corruption.
4. Writes are generally IO bound, and will not scale with many cores anyway. There are some very hacky things you can do with LMDB's writemap and/or pwrite(2), but you are very much on your own here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that writing to the value part of a pre-existing key does not modify the b-tree because you are not modifying the keys. So what Doug Hoyte's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61528450/2104010) stands, except possibly point 3:

3. Key phrase here is "are intending to RW to mutually exclusive set of keys". So assuming that the keys are pre-allocated, and already in the DB, changing the values should not matter. I don't even know if LMDB can store variable sized values, in which case it could matter if the values are different sizes.

So, it should be possible to write with MDB_NOLOCK concurrently as long as you can guarantee to never modify, add, or delete any keys during the concurrent writes.

Answer (score 0):

Empirically I can state that working with LMDB opened with MDB_NO_LOCK (or lock=False in Python) and simply modifying values of pre-existing keys, or even only adding new key/values - seems to work well. Even if LMDB itself is mounted across an NFS like medium and queried from different machines.

@Doug Hoyte - I would appreciate more context as to what specific circumstances might lead to a crash or corruption. In my case there are many small short-lived type of writes to the same DB.

Comment: `MDB_NO_LOCK` is dangerous. We can faithfully reproduce the race condition even on local filesystem. We have two threads in a process, one opening a LMDB environment for write, the other opening it again in read only mode. One write transaction includes several thousands times of writes, MB level data in total. The read thread gets inconsistent data.