# Is LMDB safe against access from several different machines?

Tags: aws-lambda, process, nfs, amazon-efs, lmdb

It is common knowledge that LMDB is transactionally safe even when used by multiple processes.

But it is safe against file corruption when several different machines (in fact different AWS Lambdas) access it through NFS (Lambda's mounted EFS)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same idea - EFS is essentially managed NFS and it seems to work well, even with multiple EC2 nodes touching the same DB. Note that writes are I/O bound - so monitoring throughput for a (high traffic) website would be needed here on EFS.

Couple of learnings:

- This will only work if you manage Locking yourself, so it depends on your usecase. Meaning you would need to open the DB with MDB_NOLOCK (or Environment lock=False in Python)
- I am not sure *how* LMDB actually does the locking - but I imagine it locks several pages at the time of a write. You need to ensure no process writes at the same pages to avoid corruption. The risk I am taking is that a key might be located within the same 'page' when different process do a write. I welcome anyone to enlighten me if this approach safe if my application guarantees that *different LMDB keys* are being used by different processes at the same time.
- I've found that LMDB itself caches a portion of the data (perhaps several pages) So your writes may not reappear until you actually reopen the database. I have worked around this by re-opening the LMDB instance before a read (performance hit in favor of consistency)
- As per several other posts, it seems we are [on our own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59808064/can-lmdb-be-made-concurrent-for-writes-as-well-under-specific-circumstances) with this kind of implementation.

In conclusion I find LMDB a great super performant key-value store and would welcome more insights about the application of it in these kinds of scenarios.

Answer (score -1):

Theoretically yes since lmdb is multi process safe and that is what EFS emulates but from different machines.

In reality and practicality it all depends on how safe the EFS file locking and apis play with lmdb internal code

I think this is generally an unchartered territory with many unknowns. Will be tough finding support online